# Unable to reset reactive form inside .then() method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I am new to Angular, Firebase and I am trying to reset my form after registration was successful. So I have a method called `registration()` in `Register.component.ts` file which will be called when user clicks on submit button.

Problem : Data is getting saved to Firebase but form is not getting reset I mean form fields are not getting cleared and if I touch any form field as soon as I submit, all the form fields are getting reset. How can I reset my form after successfully saving data to Firebase real time database.

when I try to insert the `this.buildForm()` outside the `.then()` myForm is getting reset but when i use it inside `.then()` it is not working but i am able to log the return value. I also tried using `async/await` same problem there I have `try catch` block inside the `try` block if I run the `this.buildForm()` above `this.auth.register(formData)` `this.buildForm()` is working as expected but if i run it below it is not working.

I tried logging the `this` inside the `.then()` and outside both the values seems to be same. I attached the code snippets of the `component, service, html`.

`Register.component.ts`

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
    import { MatchPassword, CustomValidator } from './register.customvalidator';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { User } from 'src/app/user/user.model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-register',
      templateUrl: './register.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
    })
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
      myForm: FormGroup;
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private auth: AuthService,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private db: AngularFireDatabase
      ) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.buildForm();
      }
      buildForm() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group(
          {
            firstName: [
              '',
              [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z][a-z A-Z]+$'),
                Validators.minLength(3)
              ]
            ],
            lastName: [
              '',
              [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern('^[a-z A-Z]+$'),
                Validators.minLength(3)
              ]
            ],
            email: [
              '',
              [Validators.required, Validators.email],
              CustomValidator.uniqueEmail(this.db)
            ],
            password: [
              '',
              [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern(
                  new RegExp('^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_])')
                ),
                Validators.minLength(6),
                Validators.maxLength(20)
              ]
            ],
            cpassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
            role: ['', [Validators.required]]
          },
          { validator: MatchPassword }
        );
      }
      get firstName() {
        return this.myForm.get('firstName');
      }
      get lastName() {
        return this.myForm.get('lastName');
      }
      get email() {
        return this.myForm.get('email');
      }
      get password() {
        return this.myForm.get('password');
      }
      get cpaswword() {
        return this.myForm.get('cpaswword');
      }
      get role() {
        return this.myForm.get('role');
      }

      register(formData: User) {
        this.auth
          .register(formData)
          .then(data => {
            if (data) {
              console.log(data);
              this.buildForm();
            }
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
      }
      cancel() {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    }
```

`Register.component.html`

```html
    <div class="xs container mt-2">
      <div class="card">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Registration</h1>
        <form [formGroup]="myForm" class="p-5" (ngSubmit)="register(myForm.value)">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-6">
              <input
                type="text"
                formControlName="firstName"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="First Name"
              />
              <div *ngIf="firstName.touched" class="pl-2 validation-error">
                <div *ngIf="firstName.errors && (firstName?.errors)['required']">
                  Required*
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="firstName.errors && (firstName?.errors)['pattern']">
                  contains invalid Characters
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="firstName.errors && (firstName?.errors)['minlength']">
                  min length 3
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-6">
              <input
                type="text"
                formControlName="lastName"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Last Name"
              />
              <div *ngIf="lastName.touched" class="pl-2 validation-error">
                <div *ngIf="lastName.errors && (lastName?.errors)['required']">
                  Required*
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="lastName.errors && (lastName?.errors)['pattern']">
                  contains invalid Characters
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="lastName.errors && (lastName?.errors)['minlength']">
                  min length 3
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <input
                type="email"
                formControlName="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                class="form-control"
              />
              <div *ngIf="email.touched" class="pl-2 validation-error">
                <div *ngIf="email.errors && (email?.errors)['required']">
                  Required*
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="email?.errors && (email?.errors)['email']">
                  contains invalid Characters
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="email.valid" class="text-success">
                  {{ email.value }} is available
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="email.pending" class="text-secondary">
                  {{ email.value }} checking availability ......
                </div>
                <div
                  *ngIf="
                    email?.errors &&
                    email.dirty &&
                    !(email?.errors)['emailAvailable'] &&
                    !(email?.errors)['email']
                  "
                >
                  {{ email.value }} is already registered
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-6">
              <input
                type="password"
                formControlName="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                class="form-control"
              />

              <div *ngIf="password.touched" class="pl-2 validation-error">
                <div *ngIf="password?.errors && (password?.errors)['required']">
                  Required*
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="password?.errors && (password?.errors)['pattern']">
                  password invalid please choose other
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="password?.errors && (password?.errors)['minlength']">
                  should contain atleast 6 characters
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="password?.errors && (password?.errors)['maxlength']">
                  should contain atmost 20 characters
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-6">
              <input
                type="password"
                formControlName="cpassword"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                class="form-control"
              />

              <div
                *ngIf="myForm?.errors && (myForm?.errors)['passwordMismatch']"
                class="validation-error text-center"
              >
                password mismatch
              </div>
            </div>
            <small id="passwordHelp" class="text-center p-2 form-text text-muted"
              >password requirements: 1 letter,1 numeric, 1 special character and
              min length 6</small
            >
          </div>
          <br />
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="role" required>
                <option value="">Select Role</option>
                <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
              </select>
              <div *ngIf="role.touched" class="pl-2 validation-error">
                <div *ngIf="role.errors && (role?.errors)['required']">
                  please select one
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-6">
              <button
                type="submit"
                class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-info"
                [disabled]="myForm.invalid || myForm.untouched"
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-6">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-secondary"
                (click)="cancel()"
              >
                cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

auth.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { User } from 'firebase';
    import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';
    import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { User as NewUser } from '../user/user.model';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AuthService {
      constructor(
        private authDb: AngularFireAuth,
        private loader: LoaderService,
        private db: AngularFireDatabase
      ) {}

      register(user) {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
          this.authDb.auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
            .then(async res => {
              const { uid } = res.user;
              const response = this.addUserToDb(user, uid);
              resolve(response);
            })
            .catch(err => reject(err));
        });
      }

      async addUserToDb({ email, firstName, lastName, role }: NewUser, uid) {
        try {
          await this.db
            .object(`users/${uid}`)
            .set({ uid, email, firstName, lastName, role });
          return 'user Added succesfully';
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
          return error;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `NgZone.run(() => { this.buildForm(); });` ?

Comment: I guess rebuilding the form in the `register` method is an attempt to reset it...? @Gilsfav suggestion will likely solve your problem and you can do a simple reset. But you'll get validation to be fired and your required fields will be marked as invalid. In this case you'll need  `FormGroupDirectctive.resetForm()` instead of `FormGroup.reset()`.

Comment: i tried @Gilsdav solution same problem it is not getting reset

Comment: @jpavel thankyou verymuch i works but i am having the `email is available` helper text below email field

Comment: I also want to know why  `this.formBuild()` not worked

Comment: form fields are getting cleared but submit button is not getting disabled

Comment: Seems you are having problems with ChangeDetection. Try to avoid `NgZone.run(()` as it will cause ChnageDetection run for your whole app. Use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` instead.

Comment: @saketh, I'll answer below. If it solves your problem, please, mark as the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, and about the reason why `this.buildForm()` hasn't worked in the first place... well I'm not sure, but maybe it's just a matter of timing. You're replacing the form for another form with the exact same fields. Something inside angular thinks that's the same form. If I'm right (sorry for not having the time to go to the source code to check it out) you'd managed to do it by setting myForm to null, and, in a `setTimtout`, build the form again.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your ts code:

```js
@ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) _formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective;
// If you're using @angular 8, use:
// @ViewChild(FormGroupDirective, {static: false}) _formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective;

...

register(formData: User) {
  this.auth
      .register(formData)
      .then(data => {
        if (data) {
          // If you use this.myForm.reset(), the validators will be
          // fired after the reset and you'll get some validation messages
          // for the fields with Validators.required, so use:

          this._formGroupDirective.resetForm();

          // Mark the email as untouche or the e-mail valid message will be shown
          this.myForm.get('email').markAsUntouched();
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
}
```

And to avoid showing the validation message (*email is available*) for the e-mail when it's valid after you have submited the new value and cleared your form, you'll need to change your template code to:

```html
<div *ngIf="myForm?.get('email')?.valid && !myForm.get('email')?.untouched" class="text-success">
  {{ myForm?.get('email')?.value }} is available
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer my question. Same problem `markasUntouched()` is not working i believe still i am getting `email is available` and also i checked the `email` html tag after the submit is clicked it still has `ng-touched` class on it

Comment: Tell me about the service `this.auth.register`. You'll reset the form when receive data, is that correct? If it's not, you should take the markAsUntouched() from inside the `if` statement (maybe in an `else`?).

Comment: Another thing I've never tried and you did is treat the control by its name in the template. Normally I'd have done `myForm.get('email')?.valid && !myForm.get('email')?.untouched` instead of `email.valid && !email.untouched`. I've kept the latter in my answer as you were using it apparently without any issues. Take a closer look at it.

Comment: `this.auth.register` will return `user Added succesfully` if data inserted in to firebase else it will throw a `error`. And i haven't tried the `myForm.get('email')` before, but i will try and let you know